# Read xls file with API POI Exception Initialisation of record 0x203(NumberRecord) left 4 bytes remaining still to be read

Tags: java, api, apache-poi

I write java class to read xls file, class works fine when I read many xls file, but doesn't work if I try to read a file that I receive, and I have to read this file :(

```
public int readData() {
    try {
        excelFile = new File(excelFullFileName);
        fis = new FileInputStream(excelFile);
        workBook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        if (sheetName != null && !sheetName.equals("")) {
            sheet = workBook.getSheet(sheetName);
        } else {
            sheet = workBook.getSheetAt(0);
            sheetName = sheet.getSheetName();
        }

        sheetRecords.setSheetName(sheetName);
```

When set workBook catch exception

Exception: org.apache.poi.hssf.record.RecordInputStream$LeftoverDataException: Initialisation of record 0x203(NumberRecord) left 4 bytes remaining still to be read.

If I try to past e copy records on a new xls, java code works fine.
I think it is a file issue, but how I can read original xls file??

Help me please :(

Comment: Did you make sure you're running the very latest version of Apache POI?

Comment: Hi, I use poi-3.17.jar